# Цифры сделать калькуляторном виде

Tags: javascript

У меня на странице цена товара выводится типа таким образам `20000 30000`, ломаю голову как сделать так чтобы цена была `20 000, 30 000, 100 000, 2 000`,  вот конечно сдесть margin большой, что бы чуть чуть оталкивал, понимаю что сумму нужна обернуть span скриптом обработать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(123135));
```

```js
const price = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(1233414135);

document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 
  price
    .split(/\s/)
    .map(e => `<span>${e}</span>`)
    .join('');
```

```css
span:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px; /* тут укажите своё расстояние */
}
```

```html
<div id="price"></div>
```

Comment: Круто, но промежуток большой, как можно уменшить?

Comment: Спасибо! а если таких цифр будет очень много, не будет долго загружатся сайт?

Comment: @JuniorDjango, их же там не миллиарды, чтобы сайт заметно просел.